# return meta redirect in ajax response

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework, redirect, meta-tags

I want to return a meta redirect tag in my Ajax response. How can this be done ?

I have a Zend Controller where in my init function I check for the session expiration. If the session already expired and the request was ajax I want to return a meta redirect tag to my log in controller.

If there is a better was please let me know.

```
public function init()
{
    if ($sessionExpired)
    {
        if($this->_request->isXmlHttpRequest()){               
            $this->getResponse()->setBody('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url='.APP_URL.'/authentication/loginform'.'">');                        
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your AJAX response return HTML normally? What do you do with that HTML client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of redirecting with a meta tag, you could use the `window.location` property:

```
 $this->getResponse()->setBody(
     "<script>"
    ."window.location.href='".APP_URL."/authentication/loginform';"
    ."</script>"
     );
```